# Selenium Excel VBA - set value in the dropdown of choice having the same class name

Tags: excel, vba, selenium-chromedriver

I am developing code to log into a website and complete a webform application. It's all working so far. The trouble is a series of dropdowns that appear on page 6. There can any number of these, depending on the earlier answers.

The dropdowns look like this:

```html
<div class="grid-row gi-component gi-dropdown"> 
 <label for="page_06_relation" class="tablet:grid-col-4 gi-dropdown__label undefined iconed-false required-true">This is the relationship</label> 
 <select id="page_06_relations" name="relation" aria-required="true" class="tablet:grid-col-6 gi-dropdown__select undefined"> 
 <option value="default">Relation</option> 
 <option value="19">Child</option> 
 <option value="31">Appointed Guardian</option> 
 <option value="53">Domestic partner</option> 
 <option value="05">Grandchild</option> 
 <option value="04">Grandparent</option> 
 <option value="13">Mother/Father-in-law</option> 
 <option value="03">Parent</option> 
 <option value="14">Sibling</option> 
 <option value="11">Son/Daughter-in-law</option> 
 <option value="01">Spouse</option> 
 <option value="17">Stepchild</option> 
 <option value="16">Stepparent</option> 
 <option value="15">Ward</option> 
 <option value="G9">Other</option> 
 </select> 
 </div>
```

This ALMOST works. It sets the first dropdown to Spouse, clicks the second dropdown then resets the first dropdown to Parent.

```
bot.FindElementsByCss("[class='grid-row gi-component gi-dropdown']")(1).Click
bot.FindElementByXPath("//*[text()='Spouse']").Click
bot.FindElementsByCss("[class='grid-row gi-component gi-dropdown']")(2).Click
bot.FindElementByXPath("//*[text()='Parent']").Click`
```

so I attempted to iterate the selections but get errors with the attempts:

object does not support method
`bot.FindElementByXPath("//*[text()='Parent']")(2).Click`
Expected: end of statement.
`bot.FindElementByXPath("//*[text()='Parent']")[2].Click`

Aren't the square brackets are more consistent with a java? Wasn't sure but thought it worth a try.

I've got a worksheet with formulas to sort out how many dropdowns should be available in relation to the previous answers and the desired selection. The goal is to click the target dropdown (the 2nd one, the 7th or whichever) and select the desired answer. It seems very close but missing something small.

Thanks in advance for the assistance and the opportunity to learn more from you!